# Trouble in inserting particular type of text in MySql table

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am working on retrieving comments on youtube video. So far I am successfully able to read and parse the XML files. The problem is I have to create a db of comments and videos links. I am using following query in java:

```
sql = "insert into comments_db(`video_link`,`comment`) values(\""
                        + ura[k] + "\",\"" + comment + "\")";
```

The problem is text like following present in the *comments* cannot be inserted:

> "hey this this is "very" cool" or "Hey I'm looking for solution"

Because of the `\"` or `\'` quotes. I do not want to remove them since I have to do some linguistics processing and I do not want to change the meaning (*I'm->Im is different for me*). How can I insert them?I am using java for all these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `PreparedStatement`, ex,

```
String query = "insert into comments_db(video_link, comment) VALUES (?, ?)";
PreparedStatement insertQuery = con.prepareStatement(query); 
insertQuery.setString(1, "He said, \"I'm here!\"");
insertQuery.setString(2, "I'm Here");
insertQuery.executeUpdate();
```

- [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)
- [Establishing a Connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html)

`PreparedStatement` helps you avoid from [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).